# Why is JSS rendering items of template Sample Item but not of any other template?

Tags: jss, layout-service

I installed `Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.3 XP 13.0.0 rev. 190924` in a 9.3 instance.

I then created an item under the Home item using the `/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item` template that comes with Sitecore OOTB.

Then, I attempted to request the URL `https://jss2sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/sitecore/content/Home/Sample-Item-1&sc_apikey={CD923013-41B7-46C6-B0A9-D726FB003BA7}` in the browser and it worked.

I got a response with Status 200 with the following JSON:

```
{"sitecore":{"context":{"visitorIdentificationTimestamp":637263825029421689,"pageEditing":false,"site":{"name":"website"},"pageState":"normal","language":"en"},"route":{"name":"Sample Item 1","displayName":"Sample Item 1","fields":{"Text":{"value":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum euismod placerat tortor, quis faucibus sem mollis mattis. Proin quis blandit erat, eget eleifend mi.</p>"},"Title":{"value":"Sample Item 1"}},"databaseName":"web","deviceId":"fe5d7fdf-89c0-4d99-9aa3-b5fbd009c9f3","itemId":"6e5918f1-74d4-488e-a1e3-37fb73b2a1ec","itemLanguage":"en","itemVersion":1,"layoutId":"14030e9f-ce92-49c6-ad87-7d49b50e42ea","templateId":"76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa","templateName":"Sample Item","placeholders":{}}}}
```

I then created an item using a template I defined and attempted to request that item using the same URL above (but changing the value of the `item` query string parameter) and got a status 404.

I went back to the `Sample Item 1` I had created first that worked and removed all `Presentation Details` from it and did a full site publish.  When I requested it again using the first URL above, I still get a 200 response and I still get the same JSON.

I haven't done any JSS development nor ran `jss setup` nor ran `jss deploy` into this 9.3 instance.

So my questions are:

1. Why is JSS rendering items of template `/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item` but not of any other template?
2. Is there anything I can do to configure JSS to also render templates I create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following some testing locally, the reason you may be getting an Error 404 is when there is no layout set on the item.

So, my test cases were as follows:

#### 1st Test Case

1. Create an template without any additional fields.
2. Create an item based on my newly created template.
3. Access the layout service api.

**Outcome:** Error 404

#### 2nd Test Case

1. Create an template without any additional fields.
2. Create an item based on my newly created template.
3. Add a layout to the Presentation Details
4. Access the layout service api.

**Outcome:** JSON is rendered.

So, to reply to your questions

**Why is JSS rendering items of template `/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item` but not of any other template?**

Your template does not have any layout. That is why an error 404 is returned. So, you need to set a layout on the item. It will still work even if you do not have any fields

**Is there anything I can do to configure JSS to also render templates I create?**

The short answer is **no**.

One practice that I always follow when implementing sites on JSS is to make all my items that requires rendering inherit the template `App Route`. So, you can set your layout on the App Route standard values so that all items inherits the same layout.

For you to be able to access the `App Route` template, you will need to deploy the items to Sitecore.